# Does there exist a type of discriminant not only for irreducible polynomials but also for exponential functions, logarithm functions?

Tags: polynomials, inequalities, special-functions, discriminant, super-algebra

I think discriminant is the strongest tool that I've used_ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4035405/822157, however, does there exist a type of discriminant not only for irreducible polynomials but also for exponential functions, logarithm functions ?

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) says nothing about such things. Try Google search and ask it in MSE. Good luck!

Comment: It might be possible to extract something from Wilkie's approach in his paper "Model completeness results for expansions of the ordered field of real numbers by restricted Pfaffian functions and the exponential function", which implies, among other things, that there is a system of exponential equations and inequalities that has a solution if and only if $e^x + ax^2 +bx+c$ doesn't.

Comment: I took my question earlier in the comments here and made it into a separate question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387163/testing-whether-exax2bxc-has-a-zero. @WillSawin, thanks for the reference to Wilkie -- I knew of that paper, but had only paid attention to the results about bigger languages.

Comment: There is work about resultants for analytic functions, see eg https://link.springer.com/article/10.3103/S1066369X18040059 but if you want properties about signs of zeros as in the new question by @MattF. then I don't know.